# Implementing Screen flow with Activiti

Tags: soa, activiti, business-process-management, bpmn

I want to implement a basic form based screen flow in Activiti(New to BPMN), all I want to do, is 
`user requests form -> form is rendered -> user fills and submits the form -> The form is validated -> "Success" the user gets his id -> "failure" the system displays error message`
Instead of using any Activiti specific form components, I would like the whole interaction between the client the process engine to happen over REST, would like to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely possible, but not using the out of box form engine/renderer.
You will need to build your own portal and form implementation.

Comment: So as I understand, you can implement an REST interface as a BPMN task that can be consumed by the HTML app